# AJAX jqXHR.status = 0 when calling remote URL

Tags: ajax, jqxhr

I am trying to check `username and password` through restful web-service. So I am using AJAX to call the URL from JSP. Web service is running on another machine and the `IP address` of that machine is `100.100.100.100`. When I run this programme It shows

> jqXHR.status = 0

When I run the web-service and this application locally replacing `IP address 100.100.100.100` to `localhost` It is working. But When I call remote machine using `IP address` it is not working. Why is that? Anybody can help me? I also referred the question in `stack overflow` but it didn't work.

Network is good. Both machines connected to the same `WiFi Router`. When I put that URL (`http://100.100.100.100:8080/WebService/rest/get/auth/abraham/123`)

```
               $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:  "http://100.100.100.100:8080/WebService/rest/get/auth/abraham/123",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Login Error: ' + textStatus);
                        alert(jqXHR.status);
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
```

Comment: 1) Post the code that makes this call.

Comment: 2) if you put `http://100.100.100.100:8080/WebService/rest/get/auth/abraham/123` in your browser does it work ?

Comment: 3) Have you enabled CORS on the remote server ? (*you must*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yes It worked. What is CORS Sir?

Comment: CORS stands for **C**ross-**O**rigin **R**esource **S**haring , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: How can I do with this code? Can you help me? This is for my university project?

Comment: I really need a help plzzz.

Comment: When you are viewing a page from domain A in the browser, that page cannot not make a remote request to a page in domain B, unless the domain B specifically allows it.

Comment: How can I allow it Sir? I put `cross domain = true;`. But it didn't work.

Comment: For enabling cors on the remote server see https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I  used `Glassfish server`. But now I am using` payarafish server`. Because I thought that might be server error. But error exists :(